# Encoding string doesn't work properly in java

Tags: java, string, javafx, encoding, character-encoding

I am developing a JavaFX application. I need to create a `TreeView` programmatically using Persian language as it's nodes' name.
The problem is I see strange characters when I run the application. I have searched through the web and SO same questions. I code a function to do the encoding based on the answers to same question:

```
public static String getUTF(String encodeString) {
        return new String(encodeString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1),
                         StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

And I use it to convert my string to build the `TreeView`:

```
CheckBoxTreeItem<String> userManagement = 
             new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(GlobalItems.getUTF("کاربران"));
```

This answer dowsn't work properly for some characters:

[image]

I still get strange results. If I don't use encoding, I get:

[image]

Comment: This solution is horrible, remove it entirely. "I see strange characters" -> be more specific, and let's figure out where is the encoding problem, then eliminate the encoding problem rather than try to clean after it.

Comment: Your `getUTF` method is unnecessary and probably actively harmful. A `String` is already a decoded character sequence. You only need to worry about encoding when actually converting a character sequence into bytes and vice versa; for instance, when reading from, or writing to, an external location (e.g. file, network, etc.). Note that if you have a string literal in your Java source code make sure both the source file and `javac` are using the appropriate encoding (see Joop's answer).

Comment: @Slaw How should I check if source file and `javac` are using the appropriate encoding. I am using IntelliJ.

Comment: Note: Text datatypes (`String`, `char`) in Java (and JavaScript, .NET, VB4/5/6, …) are counted sequences of UTF-16 code units. UTF-16 is a character encoding for the Unicode character set. So the code you found, taken naturally, makes no sense. (With appropriate comments and naming, it could be used to untwist a very twisted encoding scheme.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For hard coded string literals you need to tell the javac compiler to use the same encoding as the java source, say **UTF-8**. Check the IDE / build settings. You can u-escape some Farsi symbols,
`\u062f` for Dal, `د`. If the escaped characters come thru correctly, the compiler uses the wrong encoding.

`String` will always contain Unicode, no `new String`s with hacking reconversion needed.

Reading files with text, one needs to convert those bytes (byte/InputStream) to java text (String/Reader) specifying the *encoding* of those bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please tell me where should I check my javac encodings? I am using IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: First check that that is indeed the problem. By trying u-escaped text. For instance using the small app Character Map. Global/project settings, build/compile should have an option. Ideally with editor encoding just one single option. Maven (a build tool) defines the encoding in pom.xml.

Comment: In IntelliJ in the right bottom on sees something like CRLF UTF-8: line ending as in Windows CR+LF =`\r\n`, and UTF-8 encoding. File/Settings/Editor/File Encodings and File / Build (, Execution, Deployment).

Comment: If I use U-escaped `\u062F`, it correctly output `د` for me.

Comment: I have set encoding in: File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Encoding to UTF-8 for both `Global Encoding` and `Project Encoding`. Where else should I change the encoding?

Comment: I tried to add `-encoding UTF-8` in `Additional command line parameters` in: Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java compiler. But the problem still remains.

Comment: It could be a mix-up somewhere of windows-1256 and UTF-8 somewhere. A programmer's editor like NotePad++ or JEdit migth tell you the real encoding of the .java file. IntelliJ normally does not mess up

Comment: I am using `gradle`. So I set: `compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'` in my dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If someone would have problem with Polish characters, check if POM has

```
 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   ...
 </properties>
```