# Unreadable characters when I try to create a new project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx-11

It is my first time to use IntelliJ and JavaFX, so I followed [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) to practice. But I ended up with some unreadable characters and I don't know how to solve it.

[I'm supposed to get this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6sda.png)

[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxFfE.png)

fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.javafx.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>

    <Label fx:id="welcomeText"/>
    <Button text="Hello!" onAction="#onHelloButtonClick"/>
</VBox>
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.example.javafx;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/57807845/12844632 helps.

Comment: Can you show the FXML file?

Comment: @dan1st I've updated my question, can you see the screenshot?

Comment: Please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) but post the code in a codeblock instead.

Comment: Can you also show `HelloController`?

Comment: @dan1st Yes, have you found any problems with these two files?